# "content_by_lua_block" not executing sh script nginx

Tags: bash, github, nginx, lua, git-pull

i'm trying to run a "git pull" commando with sh every time i push in my github repo.
I'm using github webhooks to post on an endpoint in my nginx and my config is like this:

```
 location /github {
                content_by_lua_block {
                        os.execute("/path/tofile/CD.sh")
                }
        }
```

in the /github endpoint it should run de CD.sh script which enters the folder of my repository and enter command git pull as shown next:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "/path/to/mygitrepofolder"
git pull
```

My error.log is empty as well so i think everything is working but when i post even with postman to my /github endpoint, it doesn't pull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a permission error, i fix it using another user that can pull from that repository.
In the nginx.conf changing the user.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).